# Embedded YouTube video does not show in Firefox, only in Chrome

Tags: iframe, youtube

I'm trying to embed a YouTube video:

```
<iframe width="444" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lN_MSyrq6-U?rel=0" ></iframe>
```

It works on Chrome; why doesn't it work on Firefox?

I've double-checked that the video is working in the respective region,  deleted the allowfullscreen stuff, and checked w3schools for any iframe-related blocking stuff in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of help and asked a senior programer to help me .

the answer was the internet connection and/or windows cluttered it happened on 
img too. ( they didnt load and the browser didnt said anything) 
so it did load but ...